# IOS14, IpadOS14, tvOS14, new user permission in AppStore required for tracking?

Tags: permissions, tracking, ios14

IOS14, IpadOS14, tvOS14, new user permission in AppStore required for tracking?

Couple of questions of the new tracking permission requirements. Here is IOS, IpadOS & tvOS14 article for new transparency measurements for data collection: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/

This statement: ”With iOS 14, iPadOS 14, and tvOS 14, you

will need to receive the user’s permission through the

AppTrackingTransparency framework to track them or access their device’s

advertising identifier. Tracking refers to the act of linking user or

device data collected from your app with user or device data collected

from other companies’ apps, websites, or offline properties for targeted

advertising or advertising measurement purposes.”

-if the app doesn't use Apples advertising identifier (IDFA), do you have still have to ask the user permission for tracking already in AppStore? (another tracking systemlike Adobe analytics are clarified in the product page)

-If the app has its own permission banner on app launch, is the permission in the AppStore still required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Regarding the IDFA, you only have to request for permission if your App needs/asks for IDFA. There's a call for that matter: [requestTrackingAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanager/3547037-requesttrackingauthorization) This request can only happen once, and then it can only be changed in-app, without being prompt to the user, if you provide the tools for it (some settings menu with that option for example).
- I believe you can't customise the banner/pop-up for authorisation, however you can customise the string you want to show to your users, with a Info.plist entry (NSUserTrackingUsageDescription).